# Google differentiates between www.domain.com and domain.com with Omniauth/OpenID

Tags: openid, dns, omniauth, uid

I have Facebook, Aol, Yahoo and My OpenID working correctly with Omniauth using either www.my-domain.com and my-domain.com for the same account.

Sadly, Google treats these separately and if after registering with www.my-domain.com and then trying to re-signin with my-domain.com, it returns with a new UID and then I display a message saying that an account already exists with that email address.

I could write a hack but before I do, does anyone have some info that may help me? I've googled but haven't come across anything.

Thank you

-ants

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, yes, Google does differentiate between those two urls.

You have to use Google's Webmaster Tools to get these domains approved by Google, choose a preference from one of those URLs and then in your web server, set a Redirect 301 so that www.my-domain.com and my-domain.com will always point to the right place